# Verilog assigment question

Tags: verilog

If you initialize an array in Verilog, like:

input [2:0] A;

A[2:0] = 0;

Would that assign A[0], A[1], and A[2] the value 0? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, that's not an array. That's a **bus** i.e. a bundle of wires. So, **input [2:0]** would be a 3-bit bus.

Assigning it to 0 would not make much sense as it is an input, not an output. However, if you're assigning any other wire, you need to see what the bit pattern of the number being assigned is e.g.

```
wire [2:0] B = 3'd6;
```

That would assign the bit pattern `110` to the bundle of wires, B.

```
B[2] would be 1;
B[1] would be 1;
B[0] would be 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It's 0 (zero) not 0.
2. Verilog specifies that 0 is expanded to 32-bits (i.e. 32'b0) as required.